# Networking books for programmers

Tags: network, professional-education

I have some programming experience, mostly in web apps, based on pre-existing frameworks. That is, all the networking side of things are handled already, and no knowledge of them is necessary.

I would like to learn more about programming for networking, and networking security. I'm interested in penetration testing, and I've been reading material on that, but most of it seems fairly shallow, and focused on specific exploits and defense of those attacks. I'd like to go deeper, and look at how networks work, and networking theory. Are there any good books that cover those topics, aimed at and audience with experience like mine, preferably with exercises (like implementing sockets etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

To understand the basics of networking you have 2 options ...

- TCP\IP protocol suit -Frouzan

[image]

- Internetworking with TCP\IP vol-1

https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dec/netbooks.html
[image]

both books are theoretically  oriented with simple algorithms to explain (personally i prefer the first one ).

to understand networking from programer's perspective you should check :

- Internetworking with TCP\IP vol-2

it explains how TCP\IP stack implemented in an operating system called Minix (Unix based) 
[image]

- Internetworking with TCP\IP vol-3 " BSD sockets version"

[image]

- Internetworking with TCP\IP vol-3 "Windows sockets version"

[image]

Both books covers server-client application implementation.

And finally those two books are good too .

[image]
[http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Network-Programming-Volume-Networking/dp/0131411551/ref=pd_sim_b_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131411551)

[image]
[http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Network-Programming-Volume-Communications/dp/0130810819/ref=pd_sim_b_4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130810819)

Hopefully it will help you ..

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This book can be found on [on amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132856204).